# Twilio, handling quickly pressing star multiple times?

Tags: c#, twilio, webhooks, twilio-api

In the process of testing some new functionality, it was highlighted that if you quickly press star multiple times, you end up locked without any interaction possible.

Looking at this in a dev setup, I can see that handlers are called for each press of star.
At the moment our handlers don't keep track of the session / state, so this scenario where handlers are randomly fired will cause all sorts of data not passed at the correct stage.

I just wondered whats the best way to handle this?
Obviously `hangUpOnStar` doesn't pass this as a status into a handler or how many times.

I'm hoping there's some properties which can be set, which would validate / stop unwanted behaviour or maybe multiple star presses should be treated as one press perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that Twilio has to handle better contact their support and raise as a issue.